# Как в Wordpress вывести список страниц с дополнительным полем вместо названия страницы?

Tags: wordpress

Надо вывести список страниц-городов. У каждой страницы есть поле Город, где есть нормальное название города. Но сами страницы называются типа "Сдать металлолом в Тагиле". Боги СЕО делали.
Есть страница "Московская область", в ней страницы с городами.
Если брать page-list, то он выводит заголовки вида "Сдать ...".
wp_list_page делает тоже самое.
Используя

```
[pagelist_ext child_of="699" depth="2" show_image="0" show_meta_key="town_name" show_title="0" show_content="0"]
```

получаю такое:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это максимально приближено к требуемому, но там нет ссылок, просто тексты с названиями городов.

Нашёл такой код, но как его вставить на страницу?

```
    global $post;

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'page',
        'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    );

    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            // Здесь ваш код
            echo $post->post_title; // Например, вывод названия страницы
            // Вывод кастомных полей
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Нет записей';
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Там где `// Вывод кастомных полей` выводить кастомное поле, собственно в чем проблема?

Comment: На странице в админке как такой код вывести?